# c# Packet Sniffer - Is it normal for sniffer to miss packets?

Tags: sockets, networking, ip, sniffer

I have created a c# packet sniffer using Raw Sockets.  I notice that when I send some message from a client TCP program to server TCP program, and number these messages for exampe 1 to 50.

The server TCP program receives all messages 1 to 50 but the sniffer listening into this ip only picks up random message say 5 and then 7,8 and etc...

Is this normal for a raw socket sniffer in c#?  Is this the limit of Raw Socket in c# and do I need to go to a more low level framework like pCap, etc..?

thanks in advance!

## CODE (showed all the critical parts, excluded the library that does the parsing for packets which is similar to the code projects out there:

So the code below shows the steps being taken from pressing the start button to processing packets that are being sniffed on a specific ip address.  I am able to sniff the data but as I said, when I experiment with a TCP client and server, I am not able to sniff out all the messages being sent and received between the TCP client and server applications, only some of it are being picked up.  Say that I fire 1 to 50 messages between the client and server TCP applications.  the TCP server and client picks them all up but the sniffer that is listening in on the same IP address is only picking up some of the messages such as 1, 5, 6, 10, etc...  It has gaps.  Again, is this normal for a sniffer application or should it be picking up ALL the same traffic as the TCP client and server applications are getting?

```
    private const int p_PacketBufferSize = 65536; // this is the Maximum size that a packet will ever be
    private byte[] p_PacketBuffer = new byte[p_PacketBufferSize]; //Packet Buffer

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnStart.Text.ToLower() == "start")
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Stop";

            //set ip address to bind outside of async task begin
            string interfaceName = lstAdapters.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string ipVal = lstIpAddress.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                bool status = await StartListening(ipVal, interfaceName);
                return status;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Start";
            adp.StopTraffic();
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> StartListening(string ipVal, string interfaceName)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipVal);
            string domainName = ipVal;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipHost.HostName))
            {
                domainName = ipHost.HostName;
            }
            SetText(null, "============================================================================================================\r\n"
                    + "INTERFACE: (" + interfaceName + ") - IP ADDRESS: (" + ipVal + ") - DOMAIN NAME: (" + domainName + ")\r\n"
                    + "============================================================================================================\r\n");

            //process monitoring
            adp.MonitorTraffic(ipVal, packetRecEvent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Add("Error Initializing IP Monitoring: " + ex.Message + " (" + ipVal + ")");
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred: " + ex.Message + " (" + ipVal + ")");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }


    public void MonitorTraffic(string ipVal, PacketReceiveEvent pkRecEv)
    {
        //set continue capturing traffic flag
        bContinueCapturing = true;
        packetRecEvent = pkRecEv;
        try
        {
            //initialize a new socket
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipVal), 0));
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

            byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            byte[] byOut = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);
            while (bContinueCapturing)
            {
                socket.BeginReceive(p_PacketBuffer, 0, p_PacketBufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
                while (socket.Available == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Add("ERROR: on topmost level starting server listener: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            instanceCounterThread++;
            //read the data from client socket
            int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                //clear the array from current state object
                PacketHandler pkHandler = new PacketHandler(packetRecEvent, p_PacketBuffer, bytesRead);
                //p_PacketBuffer = new byte[p_PacketBufferSize];
            }

            instanceCounterThread--;
            //Logging.Add("DEBUG: " + instanceCounterThread.ToString());
            if ((instanceCounterThread == 0) && (!bContinueCapturing))
            {
                packetRecEvent.fire(null, "============================================================================================================\r\n\r\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.ToLower().IndexOf("disposed") < 0)
            {
                Logging.Add("INFO Socket Error: " + ex.Message);
                //MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most likely, your sniffer code is just buggy. Please show your actual code

Comment: hmm I will post he code, the library itself I am using that looks like most people have been using from sample projects that are dispersed throughout the web.  Thanks for looking at this in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.  It was a threading issue with the way I was managing incoming buffer data and managing threads for each process.

thanks.

Comment: And is the problem visible in the code fragments you have shown? Just curious, whether your choice of code parts you do not show was correct. If the problem IS visible in the shown code, then please, as part of thius answer, show what you changed to fix the problem.

Comment: It was a fix on the implementation of BeginReceive in the while loop and the threading that resulted for each loop.  The hardest part of this was keeping track of all the different threads for each beginreceive and making sure each instance or thread was handled/executed correctly.  thanks again.